# Using if else in for body CMD

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, cmd, xcopy

Program have 2 argument 1-folder name 2- file name and if 2- argument equal to txt file name in current directory echo message  else copy all txt files to folder given as first argument

This how i try

```
@echo off
FOR %%f in (*.txt) do  ( IF %%f==%2  ( ECHO PARAM 2 IS NOT COPIED ) ELSE  xcopy %%f "%1\"  )
)
FOR %%f in ("%1\*.txt") do echo %%f>>"%1\logcopy.txt"
```

in result program cout message and copy all files to folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for %%f in (*.txt) do if /i "%%~ff"=="%~f2" ( 
    echo "%~2" is not copied
) else (
    xcopy /i "%%~ff" "%~1\."
)
```

for each .txt file (`%%f`), if its name and extension (`%%~nxf`) match the second argument (`%~2` is the second argument without quotes, if present) echo message, else, xcopy the file (with full path) to the target folder indicated as first argument

Comment: in any case program doesn't work http://prntscr.com/4z07bu   . It copy all files to folder in case when "%%~nxf" == "%~2"

Comment: @Lord_of_Games, as you are passing a full path to a file as the second argument (a text file is indicated in the question), the condition needs to be changed. Answer updated to check full paths. If you prefer to check the name of the file against the name of the passed argument, change condition to `"%%~nxf"=="%~nx2"`